# Strategy-Pattern: Surppress warning of exception for specific test in JUnit when not all method throw an exception

Tags: java, exception, junit, strategy-pattern

**Code for illustration:**

```java
public Interface FlightBehaviour {
    void fly();
}

public class Fly implements FlightBehaviour {
    @Override
    public void fly() throws CrashWithObject {
        // does something to fly
    }
}

public class CanNotFly implements FlightBehaviour {
    @Override
    public void fly() {
        // does not fly
    }
}

public class Bird() {
    private FlightBehaviour fly;
    
    public void setFlightBehaviour(FlightBehaviour flightBehaviour) {
        this.car = car;
    }

    @Override
    public void fly() throws CrashWithObject {
        car.fly();
    }
}
```

**JUnit:**

```java
@Test
public void testFlighBehaviourOfNonFlyingBird() {
    // ...
    Bird plasticDuck = new Bird();
    plasticDuck.setFlightBehaviour(new CanNotFly());
    plasticDuck.fly(); //Compiler shows that an Exception is thrown
    // However, I know that this will never happen since my Bird can't fly 
    // and therefore never throws an exception
    // ...
}
```

This is a simple replication of my implementation. I'm using the strategy pattern as you can see.

My Question is: How can I suppress the warning that is given?

Comment: no, it tells you that an Exception can be thrown, because the signature of that method in the RaceCar  and MyCar classes say it can.

Comment: @Stultuske Yes, indeed. However, as a developer, I know that my `Bus` will never throw an exception. Can I tell the compiler to ignore this, since it will never receive an exception for `Bus`?

Comment: @GentleSama cast the variable to be a `Bus`, or declare it to be a `Bus` instead of a `Car`. If it's declared as a `Car`, the compiler assumes that it behaves like any unknown implementation of `Car`.

Comment: who cares whether or not Bus throws that or not, it's myCar you are testing, and myCar can actually throw that.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff I'm sorry, my Naming was very confusing. I've edited it in order to be more comprehensible. Unfortunately I cannot cast it. Since my Object only implements a certain `Strategy` (Strategy-Patter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a test case, you shouldn't *assume* that the exception can't be thrown, but instead test that (by making the test fail in case of an exception, maybe after trying to provoke it).

With your (strategy pattern based) code structure, it's close to impossible for the compiler to deduce that no exception will be thrown. We as humans already face a hard job with that reasoning (ignoring a few typos in your code):

- The `Bird.fly()` method only throws `CrashWithObject` if `fly.fly()` does.
- `fly` has been most recently been set to be a `CannotFly` in `plasticDuck.setFlightBehaviour(new CanNotFly());`.
- `CannotFly.fly()` does not throw `CrashWithObject`.
- Probably, `setFlightBehaviour()` isn't called anywhere else for this `Bird` instance, but that needs a thorough analysis of the complete application to be really sure about that.
- So we expect the `fly` field still to hold an instance of `CannotFly` at the time of the `plasticDuck.fly()` call, which allows us to conclude that no `CrashWithObject` can be thrown.

You see, it needs a lot of non-trivial reasoning across various code snippets to come to the no-exception conclusion, a depth of reasoning that I don't expect to see in a compiler anytime soon.